# Using signature to send NFT

Tags: signature, transfer, eip712

is it possible to use signatures (EIP-712) to execute transactions.
For example Person A gives his signature to a Smart Contract, to transfer A's NFT.
Now there is person B, which wants to buy the NFT.
Can the Contract now just execute the signed transaction of Person A to send Person B the NFT?

EDIT: And maybe someone could tell me if it works, what would happen when Person A sends the NFT to someone else in the meanwhile

I apprecieate every answer :)
Luca

Comment: You cannot use signatures to execute functions. You must execute a function and pay gas fees to transfer an NFT.

Comment: Yeah, but think about a contract having a saved signature from Person A, and Person B will execute the signed function by calling a method of the contract

Comment: There is a function called `approve` in ERC-721 standard which approves another address to transfer the given token ID. I guess this is what you are asking for.

Comment: No its sadly not. What I want to do is a bit more complex. I would need the owner to approve someone before him even being the owner. So my next thought is that if he could give signature to approve someone or directly give the token to someone, before transferring it to him. You see the problem? :/

Comment: Maybe you could tell me what the use case of a signature really is, if things like this dont work

Comment: Afaik: You can get the public key of the signer from a signed message. It is used to verify the signer of the message on off-chain applications. Could you give an example of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Well, Im working on a DApp which I dont want to explain the use behind it. But what I need to do, is that for example Person A mints the token, and then there can be anyone, and transfer it from his wallet to the own one. I got it to work, by restricting the transfer-method to approved accounts only. But this is very much of trusting that the owner would approve someone. So I wanted to use the contract as third-party to controll everything. But cant get it to work, when the contract initiates EOA-transactions....

Comment: The biggest problem is, that the person minting the token, doesnt know to where the token will go to later

Comment: https://medium.com/mycrypto/the-magic-of-digital-signatures-on-ethereum-98fe184dc9c7 when I read that site right, under "signed transactions" you could also do that on transactions

Answer (score 0):

There's [EIP-2612](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-2612) (currently in draft mode subject to changes).

The EIP allows creating a signature that combined with `transferFrom` allows a single transaction to transfer tokens. A disadvantage is that it requires support from tokens, so it can't be used with an unsupported token.

If there are two signatures for the same token what would happen depends on the contract implementation. I'd guess that the first executed will be able to transfer the tokens and the others will fail.

Comment: Is it supported by Standard Ether? And can the contract "save" the signature, and execute the transaction later? Because thats what I didnt quite get of the description on the site. But thank you very much :)